# Gitlab: How can I get the contents of multiple files using the REST API?

Tags: rest, gitlab, gitlab-api

Specifically, spanning a large project with multiple sub-groups/projects and as fast as possible (presumably in 1 request?). Using REST API as I want the contents in an area that is and cannot be a git repository.

The files I'm looking for the contents of specifically are small with a few lines of text that all have the same, unique file extension.

An example that almost does what I want (I think) is using search with blob scope:

```
https://gitlab.com/api/v4/projects/123456789/search?scope=blobs&search=filename:*.fileextension
```

(with some pagination & access token stuff afterwards)

The issue I'm facing is that the json object I get as a response has a data item that contains only a portion of the file contents. I'm unsure if there's a way to extend the data received or otherwise guarantee I get the entire contents (I'm also not super clear on what blob is giving me, branch/commit wise - I want the "most recent" version of a file in the main branch). I've tried looking at the documentation but I don't see anywhere explaining what the response items "are" or if there's anyway to modulate the response, etc.

Not set on using search with blob scope, just seemed to be close to what I want.